# Symlinking shared libraries from a platform-specific directory

Tags: file-system, bash, installer

We have a setup script for setting up a development environment, and setting up the image libraries is getting a bit messy:

```
# this is to get PNG and JPEG support working in PIL on Ubuntu
if [ -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ] ; then # 64 bit ubuntu
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
fi

if [ -d /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ] ; then # 32 bit ubuntu
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
fi

if [ -d /usr/lib64/ ] ; then # Redhat
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libz.so /usr/lib/
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if your script should consist of `elifs` instead of `ifs`. I'm going to assume that it should be `elifs` since you don't want to be overwriting your links. If not just remove `break` or reverse the order of the directories.

```
for dir in /usr/lib{/x86_64-linux-gnu,/i386-linux-gnu,64}; do
    if [[ -d $dir ]]; then
        sudo ln -s $dir/{libfreetype,libz,libjpeg}.so /usr/lib
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you can do the if statement to set a variable to the first part of the path, then put all the file copies at the end after that.

(Warning: My bash is kind of bad. Haven't used it for a while. I think this is how it's done though... Might need quotes around the libpath assignments?)

```
# this is to get PNG and JPEG support working in PIL on Ubuntu
if [ -d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ] ; then # 64 bit ubuntu
    libpath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
fi

if [ -d /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ ] ; then # 32 bit ubuntu
    libpath=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
fi

if [ -d /usr/lib64/ ] ; then # Redhat
    libpath=/usr/lib64
fi

sudo ln -s $libpath/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s $libpath/libz.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s $libpath/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

Comment: This looks good, you can use `elif` for the last two if statements as only 1 option should be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of dryness, and invoking as small number of commands as possible.

```
for dir in /usr/lib{/x86_64-linux-gnu,/i386-linux-gnu,64}; do
    [ -d $dir ] && echo $dir
done | {read dir;
for lib in {libfreetype,libz,libjpeg}.so; do
    echo ln -s $dir/$lib /usr/lib/
done} | sudo bash
```